# Moving more than one subdirectory in a git repo into a separate repository

Tags: git

I have a git repo with mutiple subdirectories. I want to migrate a few subdirectories into another git repo. I'm able to migrate a single subdirectory by following the instructions given at http://www.geekaholic.org/2010/02/splitting-git-repo.html.
Can I migrate more than one subdirectory into a git repo of their own?

Example :

My current project structure

```
MyProjectRepo
--dir1
--dir2
:
--dirn
.git
```

Now I want to keep MyProjectRepo as it is, I have another repo called NewRepo, where I want a structure like this:

```
NewRepo
--dir4
--dir7
--dir10
.git
```

Thank You